# TypeError: storageRef.getDownloadURL is not a function

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

```
exports.add = async (req, res) => {
  const { body } = req;
  var storageRef = fb.firebaseAdmin
    .storage()
    .bucket(
      "gs://test-ptoject-2147f.appspot.com); var filename='computer.jpg'; var path='./computer.jpg'"
    );

  try {
    if (filename == undefined) {
      return res.status(400).send({ message: 'Please upload a file!' });
    }

    const storage = await storageRef.upload(path, {
      public: true,
      destination: `/uploads/${filename}`,
      metadata: {
        firebaseStorageDownloadTokens: uuidv4(),
      },
    });
    res.status(200).send({ message: 'File uploaded successfully.!' });

    storageRef.getDownloadURL().then(function (url) {
      const image = doc('computer');
      image.src = url;
      console.log('your url is:', url);
    });
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the Admin SDK, with the following code

```
var storageRef = fb.firebaseAdmin
    .storage()
    .bucket(...);
```

you actually define a [`Bucket`](https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/storage/latest/Bucket.html) and there isn't any `getDownloadURL()` method for a Bucket.

You should call the [`getSignedUrl()`](https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/storage/latest/File.html#getSignedUrl) method on a `File`. The `getDownloadURL()`  method is only for the JavaScript SDK.

The following should do the trick (untested):

```
const storage = await storageRef.upload(path, {
  public: true,
  destination: `/uploads/${filename}`,
  metadata: {
    firebaseStorageDownloadTokens: uuidv4(),
  },
});

const signedUrlResponse = await storageRef.getSignedUrl();
const url = await signedUrlResponse[0];
```

---

Note that it seems there is a typo/problem in this part of your code, with the value you pass to the `bucket()` method:

```
  var storageRef = fb.firebaseAdmin
    .storage()
    .bucket(
      "gs://test-ptoject-2147f.appspot.com); var filename='computer.jpg'; var path='./computer.jpg'"
    );
```